# System contains LVM volume, but no LVM tools are installed

Tags: lvm

I've inherited a system that contains a mount point at `/var/lib/couchdb-backups`. I presume this is volume is managed with LVM. because the disk is located at `/dev/mapper/*`.

Yet no tools for managing lvm volumes are installed on the system. It is very unlikely that they were removed.

- pvdisplay
- pvs
- lvdisplay
- lvscan
- ect....

```
fdisk -l

Disk /dev/vda: 21.5 GB, 21474836480 bytes
181 heads, 40 sectors/track, 5793 cylinders, total 41943040 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xeb5e1fcc

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/vda1   *        2048    41941319    20969636   83  Linux

Disk /dev/vdb: 1342.2 GB, 1342177280000 bytes
16 heads, 63 sectors/track, 2600634 cylinders, total 2621440000 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x08040000

Disk /dev/vdb doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/mapper/couchdb-backups: 1342.2 GB, 1342175182848 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 163176 cylinders, total 2621435904 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/mapper/couchdb-backups doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

```
cat /etc/fstab
/dev/vda1   /   ext4    rw,relatime,data=ordered    0   1
/swapfile   none    swap    defaults    0   0
none    /run/shm    tmpfs   rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev,relatime 0   0
/dev/mapper/couchdb-backups /var/lib/couchdb    ext4    noauto  0   0
```

How can I verify this is an LVM volume?
Are there other tools beside `pvdisplay` and `pvs` that could have been used to create it?

**Update**

Thanks to Viveks comment, I discovered I mistakenly assumed it was an LVM disk, when it actually is an encrypted disk.

```
lsblk
NAME                     MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sr0                       11:0    1   364K  0 rom
vda                      253:0    0    20G  0 disk
└─vda1                   253:1    0    20G  0 part  /
vdb                      253:16   0   1.2T  0 disk
└─couchdb-backups (dm-0) 252:0    0   1.2T  0 crypt /var/lib/couchdb
```

Comment: check `lvscan` which might be installed!

Comment: `lvscan` is not installed either

Comment: try `lsblk` this should show the all typr of partitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lsblk` should help to display if volume is lvm!

Ex:

```
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sda1            8:1    0   200M  0 part  
├─sda2            8:2    0     1G  0 part  
├─sda3            8:3    0 464.6G  0 part  
└─md126           9:126  0 465.8G  0 raid1 
  ├─md126p1     259:0    0   200M  0 md    /boot/efi
  ├─md126p2     259:1    0     1G  0 md    /boot
  └─md126p3     259:2    0 464.6G  0 md    
    ├─rhel-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm   /
    ├─rhel-swap 253:1    0  15.7G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─rhel-home 253:2    0 398.9G  0 lvm   /home
sdb               8:16   0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sdb1            8:17   0   200M  0 part  
├─sdb2            8:18   0     1G  0 part  
├─sdb3            8:19   0 464.6G  0 part  
└─md126           9:126  0 465.8G  0 raid1 
  ├─md126p1     259:0    0   200M  0 md    /boot/efi
  ├─md126p2     259:1    0     1G  0 md    /boot
  └─md126p3     259:2    0 464.6G  0 md    
    ├─rhel-root 253:0    0    50G  0 lvm   /
    ├─rhel-swap 253:1    0  15.7G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─rhel-home 253:2    0 398.9G  0 lvm   /home
```

Comment: Thats it! Looks like it isn't a LVM volume after all, it _is_ an encrypted volume though

Comment: Huh! Ok at least you know that it's not LVM.